# SQL full row duplicates and partial duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (TABLE1) comprising of the following fields:

```
MEMBERNO_PK - FIELD2_PK - FIELD3_PK - FIELD4 - FIELD5 - LOGDATETIME
```

The first three fields are PRIMARY KEYS.

I am attempting to identify and export three types of duplicate entries from the table:

1. Full row duplicates - including the LOGDATETIME field
2. Full row duplicates - excluding the LOGDATETIME field
3. Primary Key duplicates

I do not want repeated rows appearing in my three exports, i.e. rows from number (1) should not appear in export (2) and rows from export (2) should not appear in export (3).

STAGE 1

I therefore decided to identify all full row duplicates (1) and insert them into a temp table (TABLE1_FRD) using the following SQL:

```
SELECT MEMBERNO_PK,FIELD2_PK,FIELD3_PK,FIELD4,FIELD5,LOGDATETIME
INTO TABLE1_FRD
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY MEMBERNO_PK,FIELD2_PK,FIELD3_PK,FIELD4,FIELD5,LOGDATETIME
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
Order By MEMBNO ASC
```

TABLE1_FRD now contains all full row duplicates - which is fine.

STAGE 2

I now need to identify full row duplicates (excluding the LOGDATETIME field) making sure I exclude all the rows from TABLE1_FRD.

The only way I can think of doing this is by joining TABLE1 to TABLE1_FRD and then excluding the rows from TABLE1_FRD - which is fine when a TABLE only contains a few fields, but some of the tables I need to do this on contain a hundred or more.

Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: It may differ which database (?) you use. But "hstore" is one way to find duplicates in Postgresql: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630354/get-columns-that-differ-between-2-rows

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: @Sanxion so please add the Tag SQL Server to your post - thx

Comment: @Sanxion: does my answer cover what you have been looking for?

Comment: One issue appears to be if the table has multiple rows which are the same as opposed to just 'two'.

Answer (score 0):

this would be my idea: 
insert the data with the ROW_Number columns in your temp table.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNo_PK, Field2_PK, Field3_PK, Field4, Field5, Logdatetime  ORDER BY MemberNo_PK) ROWNUM_all
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNo_PK, Field2_PK, Field3_PK, Field4, Field5  ORDER BY MemberNo_PK) ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNo_PK, Field2_PK, Field3_PK  ORDER BY MemberNo_PK) ROWNUM_PK
      ,Table1.*
FROM Table1
```

Now you can select from your temp-table easily: 

Full duplicates:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourtemptable
WHERE ROWNUM_all != 1
```

Duplicate all columns except Logdatetime:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourtemptable
WHERE (ROWNUM_all = 1 AND ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime != 1)
```

just PK-duplicate:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourtemptable
WHERE (ROWNUM_all = 1 AND ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime = 1 AND ROWNUM_PK != 1)
```

Of yourse if you don't wanna store the data in a temp.table for further use, you can handle everything in one select too. 
handling this in one select would be:

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN (a.ROWNUM_all != 1)
              THEN  'FULL duplicate'
              WHEN (ROWNUM_all = 1 AND ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime != 1)
              THEN 'Duplicate all columns except Logdatetime' 
              WHEN (ROWNUM_all = 1 AND ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime = 1 AND ROWNUM_PK != 1)
              THEN 'just PK-duplicate'
         END as info
        ,a.MemberNo_PK
        ,a.Field2_PK 
        ,a.Field3_PK 
        ,a.Field4 
        ,a.Field5 
        ,a.Logdatetime
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNo_PK, Field2_PK, Field3_PK, Field4, Field5, Logdatetime  ORDER BY MemberNo_PK) ROWNUM_all
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNo_PK, Field2_PK, Field3_PK, Field4, Field5  ORDER BY MemberNo_PK) ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberNo_PK, Field2_PK, Field3_PK  ORDER BY MemberNo_PK) ROWNUM_PK
      ,Table1.*
FROM Table1
) a
WHERE ROWNUM_all != 1 
   OR ROWNUM_ex_Logdatetime != 1 
   OR ROWNUM_PK != 1
```

I created a rextester with some testdata, so everybody can reproduce it. Here is the link: http://rextester.com/AVJ95318